# Can you tell me how to Start django project in pydroid2?

Tags: python, django

I am using pydroid 2 in my android to learn python and couldnot figure how start a django project. I have already installed django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use terminal, install django, use django-admin to create your project

Comment: I had wrote this,                   /storage/emulated/0 $ django-admin.py startproject my_site

Comment: It says       Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /storage/emulated/0/my_site/manage.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.

Comment: Prblm fixed Thanks